# How to setup shipping method on magento

Tags: magento-1.9

Free Shipping on orders over x$ and order is not over x$ it should give them the $x shipping charge option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage it using Shopping Cart Price Rule:

Go to admin->Promotions->Shopping Cart Price Rule

Create new rule

[image]

[image]

Using above you can fix free shipping over x$ if it not satisfy it will consider shipping method charge as well.

Hope it helpful to you.

Comment: I have already set free shipping method on configuration->shipping method->free shipping  with Minimum Order Amount but i want to give them shipping charge  if sub total is below $85

Comment: Set flat rate and create shopping cart price rule as above you can achieve exact you want

Comment: Yeah i have created that way it's working fine but both option are showing on checkout page if order above $85 i want to show free shipping and order below $85 shipping charge $8.5.

Comment: Disable free shipping method

Comment: If I disable Free shipping method, it won't work with the order above with $85

Comment: Have you created shopping cart price rule?Then it will work

Comment: If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
    Subtotal  is  <85 
    Shipping Method  is  [flatrate] Fixed

Comment: Flat rate price will 0 0rder above 85$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37760/discussion-between-rahul-prajapati-and-prashant-valanda).